# php nested set, building links in navigation menu

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, navigation, nested-sets

I have a few categories in my database which I am retrieving [using nested set model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) something like this(number in brackets represent depth):

New(1)
-General(2)
-Console(2)

Games(1)
-pc(2)
--emulator(3)
-ps3(2)

I then have a function to handle the multidimensional array and generate the navigation menu
**--the model**
this returns the following array from database

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [name] => News [depth] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [name] => General [depth] => 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [name] => Console [depth] => 2 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [name] => Games [depth] => 1 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [name] => PC [depth] => 2 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [name] => emulator [depth] => 3 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [name] => ps3 [depth] => 2 ) 
)
```

**--the controller**

```
public function index()
{
$navTree = $this->getNavTree(); //gets array from model
$createNavTree = $this->_renderTree($navTree); //pass array to function
$this->load->view('testnavigation.php', $createNavTree);
}


function _renderTree($tree){    
    $current_depth = 0;
    $counter = 0;

    $result = '';

    foreach($tree as $node){
        $node_depth = $node['depth'];
        $node_name = $node['name'];
        $node_id = $node['categoryid'];

        if($node_depth == $current_depth){
            if($counter > 0) $result .= '</li>';            
        }
        elseif($node_depth > $current_depth){

            $result .= $counter == 0 ? '<ul id="nav">' : '<ul>';
            $current_depth = $current_depth + ($node_depth - $current_depth);
        }
        elseif($node_depth < $current_depth){
            $result .= str_repeat('</li></ul>',$current_depth - $node_depth).'</li>';
            $current_depth = $current_depth - ($current_depth - $node_depth);
        }
        $result .= '<li><a href="#">'.$node_name.'</a>';
        ++$counter;
    }
    $result .= str_repeat('</li></ul>',$node_depth).'</li>';
    $result .= '</ul>';     
    return $result;
}
```

**--view**

```
echo $createNavTree;
```

The list is created in the correct indented order, the issue I am having however is generating the links for each item
for instance the link for emulator should be mysite.com/games/pc/emulator

How would I go about achieving this, any help be appreciated thanks?

Comment: perhaps you could provide more detail on how you recurse through the trees

Comment: Please post some code :)

Answer (score 0):

I would take the easy-route and build an array of cache-levels and previously-computed paths for each level. When the "base-level" of `1` is seen again, clear the cache so that you don't have any invalid entries:

This sample code should work with what you currently have (just place this code in above your current layout-rendering code and use `$path` as the URL):

```
function _renderTree($tree) {
    $depths = array();
    foreach ($tree as $node) {
        // build the current path
        $path = (($node['depth'] > 1) ? $depths[$node['depth'] - 1] : '') . $node['name'];

        // set the current path as the current depth's path (to be used for any deeper-nodes)
        $depths[$node['depth']] = $path . '/';

        ... layout rendering code ...
    }
}
```

What it does is, if the current path's `depth` is higher than 1 (which means that there is a parent depth), it will take the computed path for the parent (which should be *full* path for the parent, not just the parent's name), and then adds the current name to it - this will give you the full nested path. Then, it stores that generated path into the `$depths` array (indexed with the current depth) for any children to use.

In your sample, you specify you want the path for `Emulator` to be `mysite.com/games/pc/emulator`, emphasis on the lower-case and the domain name. Since we're using the `$node['name']` in our path, you'll want to use `strtolower()`:

```
$path = (($node['depth'] > 1) ? $depths[$node['depth'] - 1] : '') . strtolower($node['name']);
```

I would suggest adding the domain-name in the actual line for the `<a></a>` tags:

```
$result .= '<li><a href="http://mysite.com/' . $path . '">'.$node_name.'</a>';
```

Comment: Fantastic that works really well. Much appreciated for your input.